# Entity Framework prepare query

Tags: entity-framework

I have a two tables `Match` and `Gamers`. How to create query when I want to select in one row a match with gamers who are related to this match?

Match:

```
public virtual ICollection<Gamer> Gamers { get; protected set; }
```

Gamer

```
public int? MatchId { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: You need a join or a relationship when building the model.